# How set default router for children router and set 404 page in child routes?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have main page with included child routers. In that routers i have default router(Goals component) for main page. But when i add 404 page, my child router all time set to 404 page.

How correctly set child default router and set 404 page?

my routers

```
{
      path: '/',
      name: 'MainPage',
      component: MainPage,
        meta: {
            title: (route: any) => 'Goal list'
        },
        children: [
            {
                path: '/404',
                name: '404',
                component: NotFound,
            }, {
                path: '*',
                redirect: '/404'
            },
            {
                path: '',
                name: 'Goals',
                component: Goals,
                meta: {
                    title: (route: any) => route.name
                }
            },
            {
                path: '/profile',
                name: 'Profile',
                component: Profile,
                meta: {
                    title: (route: any) => route.name
                }
            },
            {
                path: '/goal-:id',
                name: 'Goal',
                component: Goal,
                meta: {
                    title: (route: any) => route.name
                }
            }
        ],
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try :

- To add path '*' at end of router
- Remove / on children routes, refer to https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html

Like this:

```
{
      path: '/',
      name: 'MainPage',
      component: MainPage,
        meta: {
            title: (route: any) => 'Goal list'
        },
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                name: 'Goals',
                component: Goals,
                meta: {
                    title: (route: any) => route.name
                }
            },
            {
                path: 'profile',
                name: 'Profile',
                component: Profile,
                meta: {
                    title: (route: any) => route.name
                }
            },
            {
                path: 'goal-:id',
                name: 'Goal',
                component: Goal,
                meta: {
                    title: (route: any) => route.name
                }
            },
            {
                path: '404',
                name: '404',
                component: NotFound,
            },
            {
                path: '*',
                redirect: '/404'
            },
        ],
    },
```

Comment: This did not work for me - if I visit `/` directly, it will go to the 404 page instead of `MainPage`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you're doing is slightly different from what your asking. You look like you're trying to redirect to a 404 page. If you'd like to just load the 404 content instead, I'd do this, to catch everything that wasn't accounted for in your router.

Add this to the end of your routes array in your router index.js

```
{
  path: '/:pathMatch(.*)*',
  name: '404',
  component: () => import('../views/404.vue')
}
```